# Can an employer prevent an employee from branching off as a competitor?

Tags: contracts, employment-agreement, employment

In contractual terms, before employment even begins, can an employer prevent a employee from branching off and:

1. directly competing against the employer's company by forming a similar company of their own.
2. indirectly competing against the employer's company by commencing work for an company that directly or indirectly competes against it.

E.g. A twenty year "cooling off" period or indefinitely.

My intention is to prevent the internal dynamics of my company, methodologies that I've arduously refined over the past decade, from being used against me by second parties or disclosed to third parties.

My understanding is that a contract is an agreement that must be legally honored once signed irrespective of the terms so long as they're fairly communicated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a legal question, so it is likely to be closed as off-topic. But yes, non-compete agreements are more often included than not these days. Good luck getting anyone to agree to a 20 year non-compete, though. One more thought: success by secrecy never lasts. Eventually it boils down to staying ahead of your competition by continually getting better and delighting your customers, maintaining their loyalty.

Comment: Don't think legal advice can given here, but only an idiot would sign a  contract like that anyway.

Comment: @KentAnderson Apologies, it's my first question to this community. I wasn't aware that discussions on employment laws were forbidden.

Comment: @DavidB Thanks for sharing your insight though you're comment reads a little reactive and assumptive. I don't believe opting into an overtly substantial salary guaranteed across a long-term employment period (decades rather than years) for a company that favors to reeducate rather than fire is to unequivocally be considered a marker of idiocy. Furthermore, many enterprises fall under such specific niches that such a contract wouldn't always limit the employee from continuing working in the field they've been educated for.

Comment: @Clarus, Sorry if I was offensive, that wasn't my intention. I just don't like the thought of a contract that could effectively stop you from ever working again, as all businesses compete with each other, indirectly. I also think it's a tad naive to think you can guarantee anyone decades of employment

Comment: @ClarusDignus, your real problem is that people actually will sign contracts with ridiculous terms because they're more-often-than-not just "boilerplate" and they don't think anyone (especially small business) would attempt to enforce a "forever" contract. Also, if you do choose to go after a former employee for something ridiculous you risk injuring your reputation and preventing yourself from being able to hire top-people (the risk to you is more than just losing).

Comment: @DavidB Regarding your last sentence, would your concerns be alleviated if the contract mandated the employee's contractual release in the hypothetical event that the company ended?

Comment: @teego1967 Could this not be mitigated by being blatantly forthcoming about the nature of the contract and competently evidencing the employee's understanding of the nature of the contract? E.g. Digital signature, video recording etc. Regarding your second point, in terms of reputation, it's my hope that the risk will always be correlated with the reward of the risk. I can't convey enough how substantially remunerated the employee is for this risk especially when contrasted against the practices of competing bodies.

Comment: @ClarusDignus, What I am saying is that you'll cast a cloud over your reputation as an employer by going after somebody that signed an unrealistic agreement. I once declined an offer in the past partly because I found some failed legal actions against former employees who broke a non-compete that was a bit draconian IMHO (and not even close to as extreme as what you propose). The "risk" I refer to is YOUR risk, not that of people who sign the contract.

Comment: @teego1967 Understood and acknowledged. Thank you.

Comment: @ClarusDignus: Not really, personally a clause like this would be a definite red flag for me. IMO It is just too restrictive and would suggest a certain paranoia and fear from the company. Take your comment above, how would you feel if someone interviewed you and started recording you, for the purpose of gathering evidence that you are aware of the contract. It just seems a little bit strange....

Comment: You are thinking about this the wrong way. Your 'methodologies' are confidential to you. You should be able to prevent ex-employees from using them whether or not you have a non-compete agreement.

Comment: @DJClayworth In what sense? What is the "right way" you've alluded? Is it with reference to curtailing the level of knowledge and practices I share or is it with reference to protecting it (i.e. patents, service marks etc.)?

Comment: What you are basically asking for is slave labor (you have to work for me for the rest of your career.). I know of no quality professional who would consider signing a contract with a 20 year non-compete. The only employees you would attract with your scheme are the incompetent greedy ones who likely would have no intention of keeping to the agreement. And I would make a guess that there is roughly a zero percent chance that such a clause could be legally enforced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can an employer prevent a employee from branching off and directly
>   competing against the employer's company by forming a similar company
>   of their own or indirectly competing against the employer's company by
>   commencing work for an company that directly or indirectly competes
>   against it.

You can almost certainly achieve these two goals by writing a strong **Non-Compete Agreement** that potential employees must sign before being hired.

**It's important to consult an attorney with employment expertise first**, as the labor laws vary by locale and can be affected by industry practices, union requirements, etc. Don't try this on your own, or you have a much higher chance of failure.

And beware, even with a strong Non-Compete in place, they are only as good as your willingness to pursue folks who break them in court. That's not a quick or inexpensive process. Make sure it's worth your while.

> E.g. A twenty year "cooling off" period or indefinitely.

Twenty years or indefinitely are far, far less likely to be achievable. I don't think I've ever seen a Non-Compete that specified twenty years, an I know I've never seen one designed to last indefinitely. **The courts (at least in the US) don't like to prevent people from being able to work in their chosen profession.**

> My intention is to prevent the internal dynamics of my company,
>   methodologies that I've arduously refined over the past decade, from
>   being used against me by second parties or disclosed to third parties.

You should talk with your corporate attorney. Explain what you are trying to achieve, and ask how best to get there.

You may need to bolster yourself with patents, trademarks, service marks, etc.

And based on your statement above, you almost certainly want a **Non-Disclosure Agreement** written as well.

> My understanding is that a contract is an agreement that must be
>   legally honored once signed irrespective of the terms so long as
>   they're fairly communicated.

That's not quite the case.

Again, an attorney can explain the details that must be part of your contractual agreement that will make it valid in your locale and your context. Just being "fairly communicated" isn't likely to be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for adopting an open-mind towards my objective and for outlining measures by which it may be achievable, especially so when my question seems to have invoked a level of threat or offense to other members in the garnered responses. Regarding your comment on my pursuance of contractual violations, it is my ambition to legally oblige former employees to disclose the companies they work for and the nature of their roles during the non-compete period. I expect to know with absolutism rather than stumble across violations by happenstance. Is this expectation beyond the realm of possibility?

Comment: I'm not in any way opposed to procuring legal counsel and indeed will. The insights I've received from this community, though in no way a substitute for formally obtained information, are no less valuable to me.

Comment: 20 years would be impossible you would be laughed out of court

Answer (score 6):

I am not an attorney but this is false

> My understanding is that a contract is an agreement that must be
>   legally honored once signed irrespective of the terms so long as
>   they're fairly communicated.

You could get them to sign away their first born son - you still can't enforce it.  If they signed it under duress it may not be enforceable.

A contract has limits.  A non compete must be specific and must have a reasonable duration.   20 years is not reasonable.

As for disclosure to a 3rd party a non-compete is not going to cover that.  You need a non-disclosure agreement.  Unless your methodologies are unique you can't really protect them.

What about the employees you had over the past decade?  Is it your intent to force existing employees to sign a non-compete?  You should talk to a layer.  A contract you draft is likely to not be enforceable.

Comment: Contextually, my question is with respects to the formation of new company. I'm not resistant towards the notion of procuring a lawyer on this matter. When you say twenty years is not reasonable, what's the most ubiquitous/conventional non-compete period of time. I'm curious to know what you're contrasting the twenty years against (or is your deduction simply a matter of commons sense?). Thank you for additionally incorporating non-disclosure agreements and their perquisites into your answer.

Comment: Again I am not an attorney but you cannot restrict someone from practicing their trade even if you trained them.  The idea is they cannot immediately take clients.  The cool off period is like 6 months to 2 years.  And my understanding is if you lay them off then the non-compete is gone.

Comment: Thank you for the additional context. I wasn't expecting the non-compete durational norm to be so low.

Comment: @ClarusDignus It appears your setting out to start a business. I'm sure you've learned a thing or two from previous work you've done. How would you feel if your previous employer (or school) told you that you cannot use the skills and knowledge you gained with them for the next 20 years of your career?

Comment: @KentAnderson If they 1) transparently articulated contract nature, 2) conveyed that the role will only suit individuals that can commit to a ten to twenty year employment period, 3) remunerated me two to three times the salary the next leading competitor in the field was willing to 4) recruited me specifically on the basis that my educational background and current skill-sets were disparate to (or far broader than) the role I was being inducted in from scratch so I'd always have employment contingency... ...in that case, I'd perceive the risk but equally correlate the reward. I'd be enticed.

Comment: @ClarusDignus Fair enough. 3) 2x or 3x the salary that competitors pay - will put you out of business. I would not be enticed by it. It would worry me that I'd be shackling myself to a "visionary" who doesn't have a shred of business sense.

Comment: @ClarusDignus That is a lot of darn ifs.  Really you are prepared to pay someone two times the current salary and offer a 10 year employment contract?   If what you you have is that unique then get a patent on it.

Comment: @KentAnderson It's not my intent to egoistically disagree with you or aggravate you. I was merely providing context. Is it really that inconceivable to you that a company can operate with a significantly lower division labor (and associated overheads), charge their customers less, pay their employees more and still generate viable profit margins? Salaries defined at two to three times that of competitors shouldn't exclusively infer an unsustainable business model. Competitors simply pay as low as the industry obliges them irrespective of what's due or affordable.

Comment: @ClarusDignus  Not realistic context to me.  Not buying that one company is magically so some smarter than another that they can pay employees twice as much and charge less.

Comment: @Frisbee I can appreciate your conclusion in light of the limited specifics I've provided you.

Answer (score 4):

This question is going to be closed because it really is, at heart, a legal question.

But your last sentence needs a reality check:

> My understanding is that a contract is an agreement that must be
>   legally honored once signed irrespective of the terms so long as
>   they're fairly communicated.

The "must be legally honored" part depends strictly on you. It means you must hire a lawyer at a great cost and go after violators, and then you'll have indeterminate outcomes in the best possible scenario. As far as "irrespective of the terms" goes, you can put whatever you want, but if the terms are ridiculous forget about ever enforcing anything.

If you want to have a non-compete agreement, draft one up with the advice of a lawyer. Take a look at court records to see what the outcomes of these things are before you try to have "20 year or forever" (snicker) time limits in your non-compete.

Also, keep in mind that some of the best companies in history were formed when employees "branched off as a competitors".

Comment: +1 judges (at least in the US) can invalidate any part of any contract. They will do so when the clauses violate laws, or are so unreasonable as to prevent a person from earning a living in their chosen field.

Comment: Thanks for outlining a plan of research on my behalf. Clearly, I need to preemptively research what laws the intended term of my non-compete might contravene and yes, finding court precedents is a solid idea. What meaning should I construe from the facetious "snicker"? Is it that you believe my expectation is unattainable or unfair? Regarding your last sentence, that my friend, is exactly what I'm attempting to prevent. My strategic concern is **my** company's proliferation.

Comment: @ClarusDignus, yes, the (snicker) was intentional and meant to indicate that you need a reality check. Your expectation is laughably an over-reach, it almost sounds like an attempt at humor. You should look carefully at non-competes that have succeeded and which have failed to get an idea of what is practical (and that is only after _serious_ legal expense).

Comment: Thanks for your directness, your insights and for setting an cursory expectation of significant cost.